# Strategizing Post-Undergraduate Career Path for Aspiring Physics Doctoral Student

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, united-states, physics

I'm a senior undergraduate physics student who hoped to attend graduate school starting next fall, but who was unfortunately not admitted to any in this admissions cycle. I remain *very* interested in pursuing a doctoral degree in the future, as I truly love conducting research and would like the opportunity not only to pursue such work professionally but also to learn to be better at doing so. Applying to these programs, however, is not only time consuming but also incredibly expensive, and I would thereby like to do whatever I can in the meantime to make my case for admission stronger.

I've asked around for advice, and I've received a lot of conflicting information. There's quite a bit of advice available out there for those with specific "weak spots" (e.g. those who haven't had research experience, access to advanced classes, or who struggled academically), however to my knowledge there are no glaring issues with my experience or academic performance. The most common pieces of advice I've been given and seen around can be classed as one of the following:

1. **Pursue a software development/quantitative research/finance/etc. job in industry:**  I've been told variously that pursuing e.g. an entry-level coding job would be looked upon positively, negatively, or neutrally by doctoral programs. Moreover, I've applied for 100 or so such jobs over the last year and (where feedback was given) I have been told that, even though I have substantial coding and data science experience, I am outcompeted by computer science/data science/economics/etc. majors who specialize in these fields. I expect that it could take some time before I am able to find such a position.
2. **Pursue a post-baccalaureate research position:** Many of my STEM major friends in other fields have been recommended (typically year-long) post-baccalaureate research positions. There seem to be quite a few available in e..g biology and chemistry, however I'm struggling to find any in physics. Moreover, many research/research assistantship positions and REU programs require that one be a student or admitted to a graduate program (presumably due to some funding-related restrictions), and all of the PIs that I have reached out to have been reluctant (or unable) to take on a recent graduate who will not be pursuing a graduate degree in the near future.
3. **Pursue a "bridge" program:** Some schools offer a "bridge" program, aimed at students interested in pursuing a doctoral degree who would need more research experience or education to do so. I've asked around about a few such programs, and have more or less been told that I do not make a compelling case for admission as I have several years worth of research experience and performed well academically on paper. I applied to two, and was rejected by both.

I'm not quite sure where to go from here. While I know that the forum cannot offer highly-individualized career advice, I'd like to ask generally: **What can a prospective physics doctoral student such as myself do with their life in the 1-5 years after college that will most favorably impact their case for admission, where there is no obvious issue with their experience/academic performance?**

There are obviously a number of other factors that I need to take into account (e.g. just getting food on the table), however I'd like to do what I can to pursue a path that will help me in achieving my long-term career goals.

Comment: Academic research jobs in physics after the PhD are far more rare than PhD positions themselves. It's likely that, if you applied broadly, some of the schools you applied to will have zero successful applicants go on to one of these jobs.

Comment: @BryanKrause Thanks for the advice. While I know that academic research positions (particularly in physics) are incredibly rare, it remains something that I am willing to undergo the 5-6+ years of a PhD program in pursuit of. I feel that I would harbor a lot of regret later in life if I didn't at least give it a solid try.

Comment: Okay. You said you like research - what research experience do you have? And did you apply to the "top N" schools or did you apply more broadly?

Comment: @BryanKrause I've been working with an experimental high-energy group since the year prior to entering college. I've done things such as: building & testing instrumentation, developing (mathematically) and implementing (in code) a novel algorithm for reconstructing the energy & direction of observed events, writing Monte Carlo reconstruction and detector simulations, conducting source searches (collecting data, processing it, contributing to development of source reconstruction tools), running theoretical calculations (by hand and on HPC resources), & writing data acquisition system software.

Comment: @BryanKrause I applied to the "top 5" schools, and 15 others more broadly (the majority (~11) chosen because these schools have faculty conducting research in or adjacent to the subfield of high-energy experiment that I have been working in, and would like to continue working in).

Comment: What country do you want to study in ?

Comment: @Buffy I'd ideally like to remain in the United States.

Comment: What do the people you've been working with think of your application? Have you had a trusted professor look over your application materials including essays etc? Are your grades okay? Is your undergraduate institution reputable? Who wrote your red letters? On face it sounds like you have a pretty good resume so if you applied broadly there seems likely to be something missing.

Comment: @BryanKrause I feel as though my grades are okay (not *perfect*, however I have a 3.6 overall GPA, and a 3.8 in physics/math). I'm at a small (but reputable) LAC that lacks a grad program, however I have pursued "grad-level" topics (e.g. QFT) via independent study. My rec. letters came from the PI of my research group (who is at another nearby uni. with a highly-regarded physics program), my academic advisor in the physics dep., and a math prof. I have taken several classes with. The former two reviewed my essays and spoke favorably of them, and my PI expressed his surprise at my rejections.

Comment: So you applied to 20 schools and didn't get into any of them? That seems very strange given your qualifications. Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: I once suffered a setback because a letter writer (foreign born) said something in a LoR that was misinterpreted. He meant it to be extremely supportive but it was read just the opposite. While you can't ask to see your letters, you might be able to have someone else (department head) review them.

Comment: I agree with cag51 and your PI, your profile sounds good. Are you an author on any publications?

Comment: @cag51 I'm not quite sure what went wrong (I've chalked it up to competition & bad luck). I've run my CV & essays (which are, I think, pretty standard: discussing my research experience, explaining that I wish to pursue a PhD so that I can continue such work, and briefly mentioning why I'm applying to that particular institution) by my PI & advisor and received positive feedback. I've done well in my classes, and I can't fathom that any of my recommenders (all of whom I have great working relationships with) would have intentionally said anything that might be perceived negatively.

Comment: @BryanKrause I am not an author on any publications, but am currently co-authoring a paper on some work I've done over the last 1 1/2 years (which I mentioned in my CV). Software that I've written is currently being used by a couple of grad students at an affiliated institution, & (should they publish) I expect to be listed as a co-author. I've also made some substantial contributions to some open-source Monte Carlo packages that have seen relatively wide use within our particular niche of the subfield, and I've presented at research symposia. Is having authorship particularly important?

Comment: @BryanKrause Or, I should ask, is not having authorship looked upon particularly negatively?

Comment: I don't know your field well, but a big change in mine from when I applied to now is the expectation of publications. It's not so much that it should be a requirement or the absence is looked at poorly, it's that such a high percentage of applicants have something published that it is kind of an easy way to separate applications that are otherwise difficult to differentiate. Remember they're not admitting people who are merely qualified, they're admitting the top N applications vs peers. Some friends of mine had failed application seasons followed by success after their papers were published.

Comment: You might also include some statistics on the software you've contributed to and make sure that's clear on your CV.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you sound like a good candidate for admission to some R1 university in the US. But the higher ranked the institution is, the tougher the competition, and in some cases the smaller then entering cohort.

In the next cycle, I suggest making a broader search, covering universities down to at least the 50th ranked, maybe a bit more. You don't need to limit yourself there, but include some. Note that if you are rejected by some place then you are more likely to also be rejected by very similar places. State universities tend to have larger entry cohorts than some others, also.

In the interim, make sure you keep contact with those professors who now support you. If you lose contact they will start to forget your merits.

If you don't need an income, such as with family support, see if you can take on some informal research project with the aim of writing a paper. Even a survey paper for some sub field will give you some practice, though it might not be publishable. It is harder if you need income, since there aren't many jobs that you are qualified for. My daughter, in a different field and for different reasons, got a job in an academic library to fill some time, earn some money, and keep her "academia adjacent" for a year or so while she made decisions. She is now a professor.

But, keep active if possible, keep close to supporters, cast a wide net.

Good luck.

---

Of your three suggestions, the first doesn't seem very good in terms of your current goals. The others are better, but it might be hard (late) to get connected to one of them. You won't get much research experience in a year, but you could get a better idea of what research is really like. If you are near a major university and can take advanced courses as a non-matriculated student it might let you learn a few things.